# Autocomplete with MVC 4 / Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I think I am missing something obvious while attempting to add autocomplete functionality in MVC 4.  From what I have found in other posts I have been able to put together an example however the method in my controller is not being called.

What I have tried so far...

_Layout

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Controller

```
Public Function Numbers(term As String) As ActionResult
    Return Json(New String() {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

View (I have hard coded the Home/Numbers for now)

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Number)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Number)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Number)
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Number").autocomplete({
            source: 'Home/Numbers',
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I run my app and type in the textbox nothing happens.  I have put a breakpoint in the "Numbers" function and it seems that it is never called.

My project can be found here http://www.filedropper.com/testapp

Comment: Try it with: `source: '@Url.Action("Numbers", "Home")'`

Comment: Hi, that's how I had it at first but I wasn't sure if the syntax was correct so I hard coded it for the example.  I have tried it again and it still does not reach the controller.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have the `@Scripts.Render` lines at the bottom of the `body` element in the layout and after the `@RenderBody()` you need to put your script in the `scripts` section:

```
@section scripts
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Number").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Numbers","Home")',
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
End Section
```

Because your script depends on jQuery so jQuery should be loaded first.

Or just move your `@Scripts.Render` declaration into the `head` in the layout then you don't need to put your code into the `scripts` section (but you are better off with using the section)

Comment: Thanks, moving the @Scripts.Render and adding the scripts section fixed it

Comment: where Home is controller and Numbers is action !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to control errors in Chrome to ensure that jQuery libraries working properly.
if there is no problem, Try this script :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#Number").each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
    });
});
```

Then in your Razor (C#):

```
<input type="text" id="Number" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Action","Controller")" autocomplete="on" />
```

If you want to use Razor Html Helpers instead of using 'input' tag, The id attribute is the same name of Model.Member. Notice that in Controller, you must input string with the 'term' name, as written in your code.
For security reasons, you must avoid using parameters in js file that shows the site technology. The method declared above never uses js file to get address of resource.

Comment: That's the wrong way to get `data-` attributes. Instead, use `{ source: $(this).data('autocomplete') }` http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus you're right, but Sometimes it works, sometimes not! test yours which is working :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the total code project of autocomplete textbox example .

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/05/02/asp-net-mvc-amp-jquery-ui-autocomplete-part-2-editorfor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For Viewpage

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtmasterserach" name="txtmasterserach" placeholder="City, region, district or specific hotel"  autocomplete="off"/> 
 <input type="hidden" name="hidenkeyvalues" id="MovieID" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtmasterserach").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Company/getautobox",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { value: item.Id, label: item.name };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#MovieID").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#txtmasterserach").val(ui.item.label);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("#MovieID").val(ui.item.value);
               // $("#txtmasterserach").val(ui.item.label);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

For Controller :

```
public class companyController : Controller
{
public JsonResult getautobox(String Prefix)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedurename", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prefix", Prefix);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        List<autosearchdatalist> auto = new List<autosearchdatalist>();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                auto.Add(new autosearchdatalist
                {
                    Id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),
                    name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["hotelname"].ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        if (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                auto.Add(new autosearchdatalist { 
                    Id = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),
                    name = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i]["hotelname"].ToString() 
                });
            }
        }
        if (ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                auto.Add(new autosearchdatalist
                {
                    Id = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),
                    name = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i]["hotelname"].ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        String msg = "";
        return Json(auto);
    }
}
```

Keep router setting default otherwise action will not call

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "company", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```