# ASP.NET MVC 5 DropDownListFor AutoComplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I use a `DropDownListFor` helper in an ASP.NET MVC Razor view that contains a collection of `SelectListItems`. The selected item gets posted back to a controller. However, as the list of items grows the `DropDownListFor` helper will become troublesome to use. I was thinking of using a `AutoComplete` function so that the user can begin typing the list entry and suggestions will populate the list.

There are [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455610/autocomplete-with-mvc-4-razor) here that use TextBoxes, but a DropDown seems as though is would work best here.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I'd use jQuery to accomplish my goals or are there any other suggestions?

Comment: There a plenty of jquery plugins that give you that functionality including [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  It uses the jquery ui.  I has to add an api on the website to get the values for the drop down list.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mytextbox").autocomplete({
            source: function (req, res) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/mysite/api/MyController/' + req.term, //+ you can add other filters here,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        res($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.MyDisplayLabel,
                                mykey: item.mykey,
                                value: item.myvalue

                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(mymessage);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
            delay: 500,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#myhiddentextboxThatacceptsValueOfDropDownBox").val(ui.item.mykey);
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I the end the easiest (not necessarily the cheapest) was to use a customer control from [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/autocomplete/index).

Thanks for your answers.